# NSTableView ViewBased crashes

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstableview

I apologize in advance, but I am at my wits end trying to figure this out. I have used cell-based tables quite extensively up until now and have never had the kinds of problems I am having with this view-based type.

I have an array controller with a list of managed objects. They are bound to the table's content and the name of the objects are bound to the table's cell view (using objectValue.name).

There is a local array that holds the array controller's objects. It is retained.

I've set the table's delegate to my view controller. I've set the @"MyView" identifier as explained in Apple's docs.

This is the code with which I'm having issues...

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {

NSTableCellView *result = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"MyView" owner:self];

// Set the stringValue of the cell's text field to the nameArray value at row

result.textField.stringValue = [[localArray objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:@"name"];

return result;
```

I can see that "result" is not nil and that the value returned from the array is not nil. Yet, as soon as the result.textField.stringValue line is executed I get "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION". It doesn't seem to make any difference if I use the view controller as the dataSource or not. Any ideas would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
0x7fff841f13e1 <+0>:   pushq  %rbp  
    0x7fff841f13e2 <+1>:   movq   %rsp, %rbp  
    0x7fff841f13e5 <+4>:   pushq  %r14  
    0x7fff841f13e7 <+6>:   pushq  %rbx  
    0x7fff841f13e8 <+7>:   movq   %rdx, %rbx  
    0x7fff841f13eb <+10>:  movq   0x1cfe882e(%rip), %rsi    ; "description"  
    0x7fff841f13f2 <+17>:  movq   0x1cd17d5f(%rip), %r14    ; (void  *)0x00007fff9b66e000: objc_msgSend  
    0x7fff841f13f9 <+24>:  movq   %rbx, %rdi  
    0x7fff841f13fc <+27>:  callq  *%r14  
    0x7fff841f13ff <+30>:  movq   %rax, %rcx  
    0x7fff841f1402 <+33>:  leaq   0x1cd65977(%rip), %rdi    ; @"Crashing on exception: %@"  
    0x7fff841f1409 <+40>:  xorl   %eax, %eax  
    0x7fff841f140b <+42>:  movq   %rcx, %rsi  
    0x7fff841f140e <+45>:  callq  0x7fff8401d97b            ; _NSNoteInCrashReports  
    0x7fff841f1413 <+50>:  movq   0x1cfea3a6(%rip), %rsi    ; "callStackSymbols"  
    0x7fff841f141a <+57>:  movq   %rbx, %rdi  
    0x7fff841f141d <+60>:  callq  *%r14  
    0x7fff841f1420 <+63>:  movq   0x1cfeb951(%rip), %rsi    ; 
"componentsJoinedByString:"  
    0x7fff841f1427 <+70>:  leaq   0x1cd61e12(%rip), %rdx    ; @"'\n'"  
    0x7fff841f142e <+77>:  movq   %rax, %rdi  
    0x7fff841f1431 <+80>:  callq  *0x1cd17d21(%rip)         ; (void *)0x00007fff9b66e000: objc_msgSend  
    0x7fff841f1437 <+86>:  movq   0x1cfeaa9a(%rip), %rsi    ; "UTF8String"  
    0x7fff841f143e <+93>:  movq   %rax, %rdi  
    0x7fff841f1441 <+96>:  callq  *0x1cd17d11(%rip)         ; (void *)0x00007fff9b66e000: objc_msgSend  
    0x7fff841f1447 <+102>: movq   %rax, 0x1d05a372(%rip)    ; gCRAnnotations + 24  
->  0x7fff841f144e <+109>: ud2      
    0x7fff841f1450 <+111>: movq   %rax, %rdi  
    0x7fff841f1453 <+114>: callq  0x7fff849f0c86            ; symbol stub for: objc_begin_catch  
    0x7fff841f1458 <+119>: xorl   %edi, %edi  
    0x7fff841f145a <+121>: xorl   %esi, %esi  
    0x7fff841f145c <+123>: xorl   %eax, %eax  
    0x7fff841f145e <+125>: callq  0x7fff8401d97b            ; _NSNoteInCrashReports  
    0x7fff841f1463 <+130>: callq  0x7fff849f0caa            ; symbol stub for: objc_exception_rethrow  
    0x7fff841f1468 <+135>: movq   %rax, %rbx  
    0x7fff841f146b <+138>: callq  0x7fff849f0c9e            ; symbol stub for: objc_end_catch  
    0x7fff841f1470 <+143>: movq   %rbx, %rdi  
    0x7fff841f1473 <+146>: callq  0x7fff849f06d4            ; symbol stub for: _Unwind_Resume  
    0x7fff841f1478 <+151>: callq  0x7fff849f0d58            ; symbol stub for: objc_terminate  
    0x7fff841f147d <+156>: nop      
    0x7fff841f147e <+157>: nop      
    0x7fff841f147f <+158>: nop
```

Comment: You only have one table column?

Comment: Show the stack trace of the crash. In fact, probably best to show the full crash report.

Comment: **Never** use `valueForKey` to get a single value from a dictionary unless you can explain why you explicitly need KVC. The dedicated syntax is `objectForKey` or key subscription: `localArray[row][@"name"]`

Comment: @vadian `valueForKey:` is ok for managed objects.

Comment: If you bind the value of the text field, you don't have to set it. Use either a datasource or a binding, don't use both for the same value. Is the array controller in entity mode or in class mode?

Comment: @Willeke That‘s indeed an explanation to use KVC ;) However a `NSManagedObject` subclass would be more convenient.

Comment: @GeneCode Not a duplicate of NSTableView example of use, the answers are cell based table views, this a view based table view.

Comment: Answers: This is a single column table. NSArrayController is in Entity mode.  According to Apple's docs, if I have a delegate (which I need) I have to implement  tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:. I tried not setting a value to result.textField.stringValue and just returning "result", but that didn't work either. Sorry, but the discussion about objectForKey vs valueForKey is a bit irrelevant. I have tried to pass numerous values/objects and all have had the same result.

Comment: Maybe your view id is not set properly.

Comment: If you bind the value of the text field properly, setting stringValue and `viewForTableColumn` can be omitted. Is `[[localArray objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:@"name"]` `nil`?

Answer (score 1):

I looked at Apple's TableViewPlayground code and noticed that the line similar to...

NSTableCellView *result = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"MyView" owner:self];

was different in that the owner object they sent was nil...

NSTableCellView *result = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"MyView" owner:nil];

Making that adjustment in my code made all the difference. However, the whole point of this was to allow the user to edit the data in the cells directly. With the owner now being nil (NSObject), my controller was no longer the target and the action after editing the textField was not being called. I remember reading in Apple's docs...

Note: Calling makeViewWithIdentifier:owner: causes awakeFromNib to be called multiple times in your app. This is because makeViewWithIdentifier:owner: loads a NIB with the passed-in owner, and the owner also receives an awakeFromNib call, even though it’s already awake.

I modified my code in the awakeFromNib method so it was only called once and hesitantly changed back makeViewWithIdentifier: to "owner" instead of "nil". That worked! That was the original cause of my crash.

Thank you to all who sent replies and helped me figure this out. I appreciate it.